# Is there a relation between the eigenvalues of a truncated matrix and the eigenvalues of the truncation of the inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse

Given a non-singular matrix $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ with inverse $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$, and the submatrix $\mathbf{A}_{S;S}\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ induced by the columns and rows on the subset  $S$, with $1\leq|S|\leq N$.  Is there any relation between the eigenvalues of  $\mathbf{A}_{S;S}$ and $(\mathbf{A}^{-1})_{S;S}$.

Comment: What's the order of operations in the second expression? Is it "take the inverse and truncate" or "truncate and take the inverse"? (I assume it is the former, because the situation in the latter case is trivial, but I figured I'd check.)

Comment: yes, take the inverse and truncate

Comment: In general I don't think there will be any relationship because you may have removed the rows and columns such that the smallest eigenvalue of the original $A$ is much larger, and then the matrix where you take the inverse and truncate may still have a large eigenvalue even though the truncated $A$ doesn't have a small eigenvalue. Think about something like $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1+\epsilon \end{bmatrix}$ where you retain the top left entry. Then you're comparing $1$ and $\frac{1+\epsilon}{\epsilon}$...

Comment: What relation would exist if $A_{S,S}$ is non invertible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such relationship exists when $|S|<N$. In fact, we can keep $\mathbf A_{SS}$ fixed but set the characteristic polynomial of $(\mathbf A^{-1})_{SS}$ to any pre-specified monic polynomial of degree $|S|$. To illustrate, assume that $S=\{1,2,\ldots,N-1\}$. Pick any $p(x)=x^{N-1}+c_{N-2}x^{N-2}+\cdots+c_1x+c_0$ and let
$$
\mathbf A=
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
0&0&\cdots&\cdots&0&1\\
1&0&\cdots&\cdots&0&c_{N-2}\\
0&1&\ddots&&\vdots&c_{N-3}\\
0&0&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
\vdots&&\ddots&1&0&c_1\\
\hline
0&0&\cdots&0&1&c_0\\
\end{array}\right].
$$
Then $\mathbf A$ is nonsingular and $\mathbf A_{SS}$ is a constant matrix (namely, the lower triangular nilpotent Jordan block of size $N-1$), but
$$
\mathbf A^{-1}=
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
-c_{N-2}&1&\cdots&\cdots&0&0\\
-c_{N-3}&0&1&\cdots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
-c_1&0&\ddots&\ddots&1&0\\
-c_0&0&\cdots&0&0&1\\
\hline
1&0&\cdots&\cdots&0&0\\
\end{array}\right].
$$
Therefore $(\mathbf A^{-1})_{SS}$ is the companion matrix of the polynomial $p$.

Comment: That's a really nice, maximally general solution to the problem, +1.